# Can the same Python objects vary in size since there is no formal initialization?

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization

I'm trying to learn some basic Python object design. One thing I noticed is that python doesn't require you to list out all data members before you are able to use them within the class. Instead, I've noticed that you are able to introduce new data members throughout different method calls on a class.

Referring to the code below, notice how I use the constructor to declare a `self.hello_world` member. Because the constructor is called for every instance of that class, I am certain that every object will contain a `hello_world` member.

However, notice how I create a `self.dog` data member ONLY if I call the `printTest` method. This data member would not exist if I don't call this method.

So my question, unlike the programming language `C++` in which all objects must have a certain object size, can python objects instantiated from the same class vary in size due to what I pointed out?

Thank you!

```
# Class test

class TestClass:


    def __init__(self):
        self.hello_world = 49

    def printTest(self):
        print("Trying to create new data member /n")
        self.dog = "Biscuit"
```

Comment: I'm preety sure yes as you can define as many instance attributes as you want. However I don't know if they are saved as new values or only pointers to values. So it really depends on what you think about when you say object size...

Comment: @RobertMoskal Regarding best practice, is it recommended to include every data member within the __init__ function for better readability?

Comment: @Teague: it depends. Ask yourself: are the people who are going to use your class expecting to see `dog` before `printTest` is called? Does a meaningful default value for `dog` exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Each instance of an object type can have its own set of member data by assigning them to `self.*` names.

Comment: I finally got confirmation on this, thank you. This was a question based upon technicality, not 'best practices'.